# LibreOffice 5.2.2.2 won't run without Java

Tags: macos, java, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I am trying to get LibreOffice to work with my Mac. We are trying to use the database application, but keep getting asked to install Java so it can connect to the tables.

I have installed Java and can see that the installed java instance is located here: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/`

When I try to manually link this in the settings for LibreOffice it tells me:

> The folder you selected does not contain a Java runtime environment. Please select a different folder.

My version of LibreOffice is Version: 5.2.2.2 My version of Mac OS is 10.11.6

I have tried the commands

```
java -version
```

and

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

where the `$JAVA_HOME` returns nothing.

Comment: That's a Java applet plugin you're pointing to, not Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: hi @gronostaj, can you tell me how to install the java runtime envoirnment? i went to oracles website and downloaded from this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/) but this seems to be incorrect i guess

Comment: You probably need to install the full JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: thanks @greg-449. After re-installing the Java libraries and enabling them in the preferences in libre office. I finally got it to work. Thank you so much for your time and effort. Please set it as an answer and i will mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the full JDK rather than just the JRE (which only installs the Applet support). This applies to any macOS application that depends on Java (Eclipse is another example).

The Oracle download page for the Java SE JDK is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html).

Download and Install Java Runtime Environment for Mac [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The JRE is not enough on macOS, you need to full JDK.